# Sorting Java case statements

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, switch-statement

I came through here a little while ago trying to find out if there was in fact a way to auto sort case statements.. Eclipse doesn't have the answer to do this automatically. So I wanted to find out a way to do this. Sadly this doesn't appear to be something addressed anywhere. Is this something everyone will need to do... probably not.

Comment: This isn't exactly a common use-case, but I suppose it might be of some help in refactoring.

Comment: I agree it isn't an everyday thing someone may need to do. But if the case statements were in fact following some sort of logic (i.e. what is more likely to happen first towards the top) then I in fact wouldn't have need it either. But dealing with a long list of case statements now I can easily scroll down to where I need versus having to ctrl+F everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

Main call:

```
package com.debug;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DebugMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fixCases();
    }

    public static void fixCases() {
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.home").replace("\\", "/") + "/Documents/";
        String fileName = "case.txt";
        System.out.println("Organizing cases: " + filePath + fileName);

        CaseHandler ch = new CaseHandler(filePath + fileName, CaseType.Integer);
        try {
            ch.readFile();
            ch.sortCases();
            ch.writeCases(filePath + "casetest.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Organizing complete.");
    }
}
```

CaseHandler:

```
package com.debug;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * This handler allows you to read from a text file a list of case statements, sort the case statements<br />
 * in natural order, and write to a file.
 * 
 * @author Vincent
 */
public class CaseHandler {

    /**
     * This denotes the use of numerical or text based case statements.
     */
    public enum CaseType {
        String, Integer;
    }

    private boolean autoSort = false;
    private ArrayList<Case> cases = new ArrayList<Case>();
    private CaseType caseType;
    private File file;

    /**
     * This construcs a basic <code>CaseHandler</code> in which a file must be provided
     * within the {@link #readFile(String)} method.
     * <b>Note:</b> The file expected should always be a text file with only the case statements.<br />
     * The formatting is not important.
     * 
     * @param caseType The type of case this instance should use.
     * @see {@link CaseType}, {@link CaseHandler}
     */
    public CaseHandler(CaseType caseType) {
        this.caseType = caseType;
    }

    /**
     * This construcs a <code>CaseHandler</code> with a file provided.<br />
     * <b>Note:</b> The file expected should always be a text file with only the case statements.<br />
     * The formatting is not important.
     * 
     * @param fileName The full file path and name to be read from and/or written to.
     * @param caseType The type of case this instance should use.
     * @see {@link CaseType}, {@link CaseHandler}
     */
    public CaseHandler(String fileName, CaseType caseType) {
        this.caseType = caseType;
        this.file = new File(fileName);
    }

    /**
     * This construcs a <code>CaseHandler</code> with a file provided.<br />
     * <b>Note:</b> The file expected should always be a text file with only the case statements.<br />
     * The formatting is not important.
     * 
     * @param fileName The full file path and name to be read from and/or written to.
     * @param caseType The type of case this instance should use.
     * @param autoSort Enables auto sorting in the {@link #readFile()}
     */
    public CaseHandler(String fileName, CaseType caseType, boolean autoSort) {
        this.caseType = caseType;
        this.file = new File(fileName);
        this.autoSort = autoSort;
    }

    /**
     * Reads the file where the case statements are stored line by line.<br />
     * When the word case is found it creates a new temp <code>ArrayList</code> of <code>String</code>. <br />
     * If a temp <code>ArrayList</code> already exists then it overwrites the <code>ArrayList</code>. <br />
     * When the word break is found it then creates a <code>Case<code> object and stores the lines.<br />
     * This then stores the <code>Case</code> objects into an <code>ArrayList</code> for later use.
     * If auto sort has been enabled in the constructor then this will also sort the <code>Case</code> objects.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     * @see {@link ArrayList}, {@link FileReader}, {@link BufferedReader}, {@link Case}
     */
    public void readFile() throws IOException {
        if (this.file != null && this.file.exists()) {
            FileReader fr = null;
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                fr = new FileReader(this.file);
                br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String line = "";
                ArrayList<String> lines = null;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.contains("case")) {
                        if (lines != null && lines.get(lines.size() - 1).contains("break")) {
                            lines = new ArrayList<String>();
                        } else {
                            lines = new ArrayList<String>();
                        }
                    }
                    lines.add(line);
                    if (line.contains("break")) {
                        String caseName = lines.get(0).replace("case", "").replace(":", "").trim();
                        Case aCase = null;
                        if (caseType == CaseType.Integer) {
                            aCase = new Case(Integer.parseInt(caseName), lines);
                        } else if (caseType == CaseType.String) {
                            aCase = new Case(caseName, lines);
                        }
                        cases.add(aCase);
                    }
                }
                if (this.autoSort) {
                    this.sortCases();
                }
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
                if (fr != null) {
                    fr.close();
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File " + this.file.getName() + " does not exist!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads the file where the case statements are stored line by line.<br />
     * When the word case is found it creates a new temp <code>ArrayList</code> of <code>String</code>. <br />
     * If a temp <code>ArrayList</code> already exists then it overwrites the <code>ArrayList</code>. <br />
     * When the word break is found it then creates a <code>Case<code> object and stores the lines.<br />
     * This then stores the <code>Case</code> objects into an <code>ArrayList</code> for later use.
     * If auto sort has been enabled in the constructor then this will also sort the <code>Case</code> objects.
     * 
     * @param fileName The full file path and name to be read from and/or written to.
     * @throws IOException
     * @see {@link ArrayList}, {@link FileReader}, {@link BufferedReader}, {@link Case}
     */
    public void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        this.file = new File(fileName);
        if (this.file != null && this.file.exists()) {
            FileReader fr = null;
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                fr = new FileReader(this.file);
                br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String line = "";
                ArrayList<String> lines = null;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.contains("case")) {
                        if (lines != null && lines.get(lines.size() - 1).contains("break")) {
                            lines = new ArrayList<String>();
                        } else {
                            lines = new ArrayList<String>();
                        }
                    }
                    lines.add(line);
                    if (line.contains("break")) {
                        String caseName = lines.get(0).replace("case", "").replace(":", "").trim();
                        Case aCase = null;
                        if (caseType == CaseType.Integer) {
                            aCase = new Case(Integer.parseInt(caseName), lines);
                        } else if (caseType == CaseType.String) {
                            aCase = new Case(caseName, lines);
                        }
                        cases.add(aCase);
                    }
                }
                if (this.autoSort) {
                    this.sortCases();
                }
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
                if (fr != null) {
                    fr.close();
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File " + this.file.getName() + " does not exist!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the {@link ArrayList} in alphabetical or numerical order.<br />
     * <b>Note:</b> This will <b>NOT</b> sort clusters of case statements.
     * @see {@link Collections#sort(java.util.List)}
     */
    public void sortCases() {
        if (cases.size() > 0) {
            Collections.sort(cases, Comparator.naturalOrder());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Overwrites the file provided to the <code>CaseHandler</code> with the cases list.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     * @see {@link ArrayList}, {@link FileWriter}, {@link BufferedWriter}, {@link Case}
     */
    public void writeCases() throws IOException {
        if (this.file.exists()) {
            FileWriter fw = null;
            BufferedWriter bw = null;
            try {
                fw = new FileWriter(this.file);
                bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                for (Case aCase : cases) {
                    for (String line : aCase.getLines()) {
                        bw.write(line);
                        bw.newLine();
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (bw != null) {
                    bw.close();
                }
                if (fw != null) {
                    fw.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Overwrites the file provided to with the cases list.
     * 
     * @param fileName The full file path and name to be read from and/or written to.
     * @throws IOException
     * @see {@link ArrayList}, {@link FileWriter}, {@link BufferedWriter}, {@link Case}
     */
    public void writeCases(String fileName) throws IOException {
        File outFile = new File(fileName);
        if (!outFile.exists()) {
            outFile.createNewFile();
        }
        if (outFile.exists()) {
            FileWriter fw = null;
            BufferedWriter bw = null;
            try {
                fw = new FileWriter(outFile);
                bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                for (Case aCase : cases) {
                    for (String line : aCase.getLines()) {
                        bw.write(line);
                        bw.newLine();
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (bw != null) {
                    bw.close();
                }
                if (fw != null) {
                    fw.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Changes the case type.
     * 
     * @param caseType The new type of case this instance should use.
     * @see {@link CaseType}
     */
    public void setCaseType(CaseType caseType) {
        this.caseType = caseType;
    }
}
```

Case:

```
package com.debug;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * This is the individual case statement starting at <code>case (Integer or String):</code> <br />
 * The last line stored in the instance will be the <code>break;</code> statement.
 * 
 * @author Vincent
 *
 */
public class Case implements Comparable<Case> {

    private int nameInt;
    private String nameStr = null;
    private ArrayList<String> lines;

    /**
     * Constructs a new <code>Case</code> using integer values as the name.
     * 
     * @param nameInt The integer value name
     * @param lines The lines within this case statement
     * @see {@link ArrayList}
     */
    public Case(int nameInt, ArrayList<String> lines) {
        this.nameInt = nameInt;
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new <code>Case</code> using string values as the name.
     * 
     * @param nameStr The string value name
     * @param lines The lines within this case statement
     * @see {@link ArrayList}
     */
    public Case(String nameStr, ArrayList<String> lines) {
        this.nameStr = nameStr;
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Case aCase) {
        if (this.nameStr != null) {
            return this.nameStr.compareTo(aCase.getNameStr());
        } else {
            if (this.nameInt < aCase.getNameInt()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (this.nameInt > aCase.getNameInt()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the lines stored in this <code>Case</code> instance.
     * 
     * @return {@link ArrayList}
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getLines() {
        return this.lines;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the integer name of this <code>Case</code> instance.
     * 
     * @return {@link Integer}
     */
    public int getNameInt() {
        return this.nameInt;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the string name of this <code>Case</code> instance.
     * 
     * @return {@link String}
     */
    public String getNameStr() {
        return this.nameStr;
    }
}
```

Example input:

```
case 338:
    // Code
    break;
case 852:
    // Code
    break;
case 2:
    // Code
    break;
case 696:
    // Code
    break;
```

Example output:

```
case 2:
    // Code
    break;
case 338:
    // Code
    break;
case 696:
    // Code
    break;
case 852:
    // Code
    break;
```

Hope this potentially helps someone out. I needed this cause I was looking at a long list of cases (1000 of them to be exact) that were sorted in no particular order or with any reason to be sorted that way. So I wanted to see them in natural order.

Comment: You should include the code as an answer, not in the question itself.

Comment: Noted and I moved it

Comment: I like the idea but this could be improved in the sense that it could be written as a IDE Plugin. With more features like ASC and DESC ordering, Alphabetical ordering etc.

Comment: I hate to say it but I am not familiar with making those plugins although it would be a great idea in that case. It doesn't handle ASC and DESC though that could probably be added quite easily to it. This one only handles ASC and it does handle numerical or alphabetical sorting.